# Azure Activity function invoked multiple times

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-durable-functions

I have an orchestrator function calls suborchestration and that in turn calls an activity function. For some reason the activity function has been invoked multiple times.

"KMA-Orch-DataRefreshOrchestration" -> "KMA-Orch-DataRefreshSubOrchestration" -> "KMA-Product"

- Azure runtime version : 1.0
- FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION : ~1
- Region : Central US
- Hosting Plan : Standard
- Original trigger time : 2018-07-06 08:00:30,989
- 2nd time trigger : 2018-07-06 08:15:41,814
- 3rd time trigger : 2018-07-06 08:43:27,074

Comment: Please provide minimal code to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Mikhail I have posted the code in below issue. https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/877

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Consumption Plan with Durable Functions, some comments:

- The 20 min to 6 hours is too long for the consumption plan, it will
  timeout at up to 10 minutes:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan

  - You should consider breaking that function in multiple smaller functions that you would chain, or create processing batches and
    execute them in a fan-out scenario.
- One of the best practice is to avoid long running functions (also applicable to Durable Functions):
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#avoid-long-running-functions
- You can also check the following issue for information about how to handle timeouts gracefully using C#:
  https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2153.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But we are on standard plan and still see the same issue.